# Turn off fullscreen in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

My cat was on the keyboard and did something where chrome is in full screen. I can't see or switch the tabs, I can't minimize or exit. I'm stuck on this page. I tried the cntrl+tab etc.. My computer is a dell and doesn't have the command button. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I fixed the Problem. It is F11

Comment: welcome to superuser: i'm glad you solved your problem, could you accept the answer so that future searches see the acceptance and because people answer questions for the great reward of points(ha ha but ture). again welcome to superuser and thankyou

Comment: +1 for the cat on the keyboard! :-) This is a major problem in my house too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to exit out of full screen using <kbd>F11</kbd>.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Refer to the [Chrome keyboard shortcuts help page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) for more shortcuts.

[image: Chrome help]